# VSCode - Black UI/Menu Font

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode sidebar and menu font is black. It is not effected by my
slected theme, so when I use a high contrast theme everything becomes
unreadeable (black background) I couldn't really find a solution to
my problem.

```
VSCode - About Version: 1.28.2 (user setup) Commit:
7f3ce96ff4729c91352ae6def877e59c561f4850 Date:
2018-10-17T00:23:51.859Z Electron: 2.0.9 Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3 V8: 6.1.534.41 Architecture: x64
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9e3r.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHmB8.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfNcJ.png]

Comment: Try: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running into [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60298) with VS Code 1.28

It should already be fixed in [current VS Code insiders builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and should be fixed by VS Code 1.29

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just tried the inside edition and everything works fine now.